# How do I reply to a late job opportunity?

Tags: job-offer, job-change, human-resources, resignation, email

**Background**

I got a job referral from a friend about 3 months ago to work in a big company, let's say, company A. But last month, I received an offer from a startup (company B) after being referred by another friend and I accepted it because by then I hadn't received any reply from company A after my online application and the referral being sent to the HR.

Today I finally got an email from the HR of company A saying that while there is not a specific position available at this time, the manager of department X would like to schedule an introductory phone call with me to discuss potential opportunities.

---

**My Thoughts**

Personally, I'd like to mention that I was hired by another company just recently and may not be able to change my job until the end of the year (I think I need to work until some time next year before considering a resignment because I just started my work from company B, also, company A doesn't even have a position right now, just potential opportunities, as they said in their email). But it is for sure that if there are any opportunites in the future from company A, I would prefer to change my work. And by then, I think it would also be a better time to talk about resignation with my current employer at company B.

---

**Questions**

1. I wonder how I should reply this email and if I should mention my current work.
2. What is exactly an introductory phone call? Should I take it and how should I talk about my current job with the manager at company A?
3. How do I express that I am open to any opportunities from company A but just unable to change my work this year, and would be very willing to talk about any position in the future?

Answer (score 5):

**An introductory phone call** is literally that.  Hi I am such and such and you are such and such.  This is the company and what we do, this is you and what you are interested in.  This is done to get a feel for possible candidates before digging into interview specifics for specific jobs.

I would totally take the introductory call without saying anything about being hired.  It's just an introduction and if nothing else you will learn more about Company A through it.  When things turn to actual interviews for the job then you mention who you currently work for and how long and explain that you applied to both Company A & B and Company B offered before Company A responded, but you are still interested in opportunities with Company A.  If it gets to the point of offering you a job then you discuss your start date with them.  If you feel you need to work for Company B a certain duration of time, then you work out with Company A that you will start on x date with them.  Then you can give notice to Company B for that date and if either of them want to rework the date to a lesser period of time then you do that as you go along.

**P.S.** I would secure backup plan start dates with Company A prior to giving notice at Company B in case Company B says, don't want to keep you that long, leave after a couple weeks...or even leave now as you haven't spun up enough to benefit us.  Still best to be honest, but make sure you have backup plans in case so you are covered.

Comment: It's easy to not mention company B in the email, but "take the introductory call without saying anything about being hired" is hard I am afraid. How can you avoid this issue?

Comment: Well I'm not sure on your background, but you can say you are currently employed but interested in new opportunities, especially with Company A.  The specifics only come out if those are already on the table...which they may be in your case in which you have to talk about it sooner rather than later.