# How should I reply to a job opportunity if my response is 2 weeks late?

Tags: job-search, email, correspondence

While looking through my emails, I noticed a 2 week old email informing me of a job opportunity with a nearby company.

I'm unsure how I should respond to the job opportunity now that two weeks have passed. Do I apologize for my late response? Should I ask if the position is still available? Is it unprofessional to respond after so much time has passed?

**In short, how should I reply to a job opportunity if my email response is more than two weeks late?**

<sub>**Note:** This question is different from *[How do I reply to a late job opportunity?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/91305/68427)*, which asks about responding to a late job offer from a potential employer, while this question asks about sending a late response as a potential employee.</sub>

Comment: *Usually* two weeks is nothing: recruitment is a remarkably slow process.  So you *should* be OK.  Answer with the usual enthusiasm and professionalism as if you were answering normally. You could *maybe* add at the end of the email add "Sorry for the delay in reply".  There is, essentially, *absolutely of excuse* unfortunately these days for missing emails, so it's best not to try to excuse yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't lose anything if you ask.

Just acknowledge to the sender your delay (and *maybe* the reason), and ask if the position is still open. In the worst case scenario you just get a no - or no answer at all.